# An error in my table

Tags: tables

I am trying to write the following entries in a table

```
\begin{table}[h]

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{@{}llllllll@{}}
\toprule
$c_{ij}$  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8         &  \\
1 & 0 & 190 & 359 & 514 & 676 & 810 & 931 & 1013         &  \\
2 & 190   & 0 & 178& 333 & 496 & 630 & 750 & 831          &  \\
3 & 359 & 178 & 0 & 156 & 318 & 452 & 573 & 655       &  \\
4 & 514 & 333 & 156 & 0 & 246 & 297 & 417 & 499  &       &  \\
5 &  676 & 496 & 318 & 246 & 0 & 156 & 255 & 338          &  \\
6 & 810 & 630 & 452 & 297 & 156 & 0 & 120 & 204        &  \\
7 & 931 & 750 & 573 & 417 & 255 & 120 & 0  &  85      &  \\
8 & 1013  & 831 & 655 & 499 & 338 & 204 & 85 & 0        &  \\
    & & & & &     &        &                       &         &\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption {$c_{ij}$}
\end{table}
```

I keep getting this error:

You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.

Any suggestion as to how to fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: Please show the document, not only fragments of code. There are more `&` characters than column specifiers

Comment: `\[ \begin{table}[h]` will give an error already, you can not have a float in math mode, remove the `\[`

Comment: @Selena: You should accept Mico's answer rather than mine. He makes some important improvements ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some suggestions/observations:

- No need to insert `&` before the `\\` (line-break) instructions
- Since the material seems to be math-y, consider using an `array` environment instead of a `tabular` environment.
- To guarantee that the eight data columns are all exactly equally wide, consider loading the `siunitx` package and using that package's `S` column type for the eight data columns.
- Instead a `center` environment, use the instruction `\centering`.
- Set off the header row visually by providing a bit of extra vertical whitespace (see below) or by providing a `\midrule` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
$\begin{array}{ @{} l *{8}{S[table-format=4.0]} @{} }
\toprule
c_{ij}  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\[1ex]
1 &   0 & 190 & 359 & 514 & 676 & 810 & 931 &1013  \\
2 & 190 &   0 & 178 & 333 & 496 & 630 & 750 & 831  \\
3 & 359 & 178 &   0 & 156 & 318 & 452 & 573 & 655  \\
4 & 514 & 333 & 156 &   0 & 246 & 297 & 417 & 499  \\
5 & 676 & 496 & 318 & 246 &   0 & 156 & 255 & 338  \\
6 & 810 & 630 & 452 & 297 & 156 &   0 & 120 & 204  \\
7 & 931 & 750 & 573 & 417 & 255 & 120 &   0 &  85  \\
8 &1013 & 831 & 655 & 499 & 338 & 204 &  85 &   0  \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption {$c_{ij}$}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are 8 relevant rows and columns and a descriptive header row/column, so there should not be more than 9 columns effectively. In my point of view, the columns should be right justified.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{9}{r}@{}}
\toprule
$c_{ij}$  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8           \tabularnewline
1 & 0 & 190 & 359 & 514 & 676 & 810 & 931 & 1013    \tabularnewline
2 & 190   & 0 & 178& 333 & 496 & 630 & 750 & 831    \tabularnewline
3 & 359 & 178 & 0 & 156 & 318 & 452 & 573 & 655     \tabularnewline
4 & 514 & 333 & 156 & 0 & 246 & 297 & 417 & 499     \tabularnewline
5 &  676 & 496 & 318 & 246 & 0 & 156 & 255 & 338    \tabularnewline
6 & 810 & 630 & 452 & 297 & 156 & 0 & 120 & 204     \tabularnewline
7 & 931 & 750 & 573 & 417 & 255 & 120 & 0  &  85    \tabularnewline
8 & 1013  & 831 & 655 & 499 & 338 & 204 & 85 & 0    \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{$c_{ij}$}\label{somelabel}
\end{center}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I am just about editing ;-)

Comment: Why `\tabularnewline`?

Comment: @egreg: Why not? I prefer it rather as eye-candy in code, to make it more outstanding than `\\`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks... I have one more inquiry... I write stuff below the table on latex but when I build the pdf, they're written above the table... Any idea why?